# File search hotkey doesn't show results

Tags: phpstorm

I´m new to phpstorm (on mac) and after some code updates yesterday i recognized that the file search

```
 CMD + SHIFT + o
```

doesn´t show up any results anymore.

After hitting the first key it´s getting red:

[image]

Do I have to reindex the project structure at any point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please execute `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE -- most likely your indexes somehow got corrupted (especially after IDE update).